# Branch name for incoming mercurial hooks

Tags: mercurial, branch, hook

In hgrc file on mercurial server I have next incoming hooks:

```
[hooks]
incoming.jenkins_win7x64  = wget -q http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/Project1/build
incoming.jenkins_ubuntu   = wget -q http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/Project2/build
```

This hooks need for jenkins build start if mercurial server pull event exist.
The problem, that this incoming hooks triggered if exist changes in any of branches, but I need in this hooks if exists changes only in default branch.

I know, that I can set python scripts and binaries for incoming hooks, but still not understand how to filter branch name.

How to set branch name for incoming mercurial hooks?

Comment: You need to write a more elaborate hook and only trigger jenkins when a changeset in the branches you are interested in is found (thus a one-liner won't do)

Comment: https://hg.openttdcoop.org/misc/files/0c722123840fc9dc1d99ff527ec0319062e36d55/mercurial/hooks/invoke_jenkins.sh might give you some idea on how to approach it